# Larvel Livewire emitting to listener from component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In `Laravel Livewire` as you know we can emit any listener with clicking events or from a component, my issue is i can emit listener with clicking on any `Html` tags, but i can't do that from `mount` or `render` function

this code work fine:

```
wire:click="$emit('changeMenuItems',-1,1)"
```

now doesn't work in this functions:

```php
class CategoriesComponent extends Component
{
    #[NoReturn] public function mount()
    {
        $this->emit('changeMenuItems', -1, 1);
    }

    public function render(): Factory|View|Application
    {
        $this->emit('changeMenuItems', -1, 1);

        return view('livewire.backend.pages.categories-component');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Emitting listener from `mount` and `render` doesn't worked and i'm not sure whats problem but creating a simple function as model into `Livewire` component resolved my problem:

```php
public function manageSidebarMenuRoutes(int $parent_menu, int $sub_menu, string $route_name)
{
    // $this->emit('changeMenuItems', -1, 1);
    return redirect()->route($route_name, app()->getLocale());
}
```

and `Html` code:

```html
<li wire:click="manageSidebarMenuRoutes(1,1)}},'administrator')" class="nav-item">
    ...
</li>
```